# Llenar select con colonias de acuerdo al codigo postal

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net

Buen día, estoy haciendo un formulario donde manejo cp y colonias, mi idea es llenar el select de colonia con su respectivo valor. los datos los obtengo de un json que encontre por internet, actualmente lleno de esta manera el select de CP

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/dist/js/colonias.json', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $('#cp').append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value.localidad)
                .text(value.cp));
        });

    });

});
```

lo que falta es llenar otro select con las colonias que estan dentro de ese codigo postal.

y este es un fragmento del json donde obtengo la informacion

```
    "cp": "76118",
"localidad": "10 de Abril",
"tipo": "Fraccionamiento",
"municipio": "Querétaro"
```

mi proyecto lo estoy haciendo con .asp, si necesitan más informacion por favor, pedirla.
espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Hola, tu proyecto es ASP.NET MVC?.

Comment: No se logra entender cuál es el problema en específico, se un poco más específico, ¿la colonia vienen en otro fragmento del JSON?

Comment: no, viene en el mismo JSON

Comment: Puedes poner la parte dónde se encuentra la `colonia`?

Comment: en el json aparece como "localidad" @VickMuñoz

Answer (score 1):

a tu `$('#cp')` le debes poner el evento `.change()`,
para que cada vez que se seleccione una colonia, le pases el `key` de tu json a una funcion que te cargue en el otro `select` con los respectivos datos de la colonia.

¿me explique?

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta trata sobre `ajax`, lo que debes hacer es guardar cada peticion en un metodo y esto lo invocas segun la secuencia que necesites, en este ejemplo, el `departamento -> provincia -> distrito` , puedes adecuarlo `pais -> estado -> provincia`, etc

```js
     //Iniciamos con Departamento
      $.get("{{url('api/departamento')}}").then(function(ls){
         for (var i =  1; i < ls.length; i++) {
             $("#dep").append('<option value="'+ls[i].dDepartamento+'">'+ls[i].Descripcion+'</option>');
         }
         //$("#dep").val(us.departamento_id); //solo en caso de Actualizar
         provincia($("#dep").val());//pedimos cargar provincia
     });
      //metodo provincia, para la cual necesitamos Id departamento 
     function provincia(i) {
         $("#pro option").remove();
         $.get("{{url('api/provincia')}}/"+i).then(function(ls){
             for (var i =  1; i < ls.length; i++) {
                 $("#pro").append('<option value="'+ls[i].codProvincia+'">'+ls[i].Descripcion+'</option>');
             }
             //$("#pro").val(us.provincia_id);//solo en caso de Actulizar
             distrito($("#dep").val(),$("#pro").val());//pedimos cargar distrito
         });
     }
      //metodo distrito
     function distrito(i,j) {
         $("#dis option").remove();
         $.get("{{url('api/distrito')}}/"+i+"/"+j).then(function(ls){
             for (var i =  1; i < ls.length; i++) {
                 $("#dis").append('<option value="'+ls[i].codDistrito+'">'+ls[i].Descripcion+'</option>');
             }
             //$("#dis").val(us.distrito_id);//solo en caso de actulizar
         });
     }
      //detenctamos cambio de Departamento
     $('#dep').on('change', function(){
         provincia($("#dep").val());
     });
      //Detectamos cambio de Provincia
     $('#pro').on('change', function(){
         distrito($("#dep").val(),$("#pro").val());
     });
```